# Invalid keypath passed to setPropertiesToFetch in Core Data

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data

I get this error when using setPropertiesToFetch. It's odd because info1 and info2 do exist in my entity.

[image]

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Table1", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)
    fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true

    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["info1", "info2"]
    fetchRequest.includesSubentities = true
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

    do {
        let result = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

        print(result)

    } catch {
        let fetchError = error as NSError
        print(fetchError)
    }
```

Without propertiesToFetch line I get this output:

```
[{
    info1 = data1;
    info2 = data2;
    info3 = data3;
}, { 
...
}]
```

Comment: Life gets simpler using the newer fetch request API: `let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Table1")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity needs to be set before `propertiesToFetch` can be used.

```
fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["info1", "info2"]
fetchRequest.includesSubentities = true
```

Comment: Extra info: the documentation of `propertiesToFetch` says "You must set the entity for the fetch request before setting this value, otherwise NSFetchRequest throws an NSInvalidArgumentException exception.".